# How does CleanBrowsing DNS servers make 'Youtube, Google and Bing forced to SafeMode'?

Tags: dns, web, filtering

Quote from [Activating CleanBrowsing](https://cleanbrowsing.org/getting-started)

> Activating CleanBrowsing is pretty simple and only takes 5 minutes. We
>   do our work via DNS, so you have to switch your DNS servers to go
>   through our Network instead of the one provided by your ISP.
>
> - Safe browsing experience - across all devices.
> - No porn and no surprises for your kids and you.
> - Youtube, Google and Bing forced to SafeMode.

How do they force Google and Co with only DNS into Strict Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do they force Google and Co with only DNS into Strict Mode?

Google and Co have special IP addresses responsible for the safe search. Safe search can be enforced by modifying the DNS so that it returns the safe search IP addresses instead of the default ones when accessing the common domains names.

This is in detail described in [How to: Enforcing Google SafeSearch, YouTube, and Bing](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227986807) at the OpenDNS support site. A short summary from this article:

- Google: make the name server return the IP address of forcesafesearch.google.com when resolving www.google.*
- Bing: make DNS lookup for www.bing.com return the IP of  strict.bing.com
- Youtube: make lookups for various Youtube related domains resolve to IP address of restrict.youtube.com or restrictmoderate.youtube.com depending on how safe it should be